# details section insert blank page on main report, started display record on second pages

Tags: crystal-reports

i having problem in details section, my report will insert blank page to my first pages and will only display data started from second pages, below is setting for my details section

```
Section1(Report Header)
only suppress blank section is ticked

Section2(Page Header a)
only suppress blank section is ticked

PageHeaderSection2(Page Header b)
only suppress blank section is ticked
```

**problem goes here**

```
Section3 (Details)
only suppress blank section is ticked
the rest all is un-tick
```

Answer (score 0):

- If you are using any groups, check if you have "Keep together" checked and try to uncheck it and see if it helps. It should be in Section Expert and also in Change Group...
- The length of one of your column values could be too long for your setup
- The page header is suppressed, un-surpress the header.

Hope this helps!

Comment: -i didnt use any group
-yes, my data is long, what should i do in order to handle it?

Comment: Can I see a screenshot of the design page? I can then offer some suggestions, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you have expanded your fields, maybe the header or footer, screenshot may help, you need to make their sized small, sometimes when the header is too big, the details section starts from next page, or you can always play with the margins of the report.